# Dropbox SDK 401 Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dropbox

I am using the Dropbox SDK and I have it set up so the app can only access the /Apps/MyAPP folder. I was testing it out and deleted the folder online. Now when I'm in the app instead of asking to relink dropbox it gives me a 401 error. I don't know why it doesn't display the view. It was working before I deleted the folder(unlinking the app online). Thank you in advance.

> PageFlipper[66893:c07] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to
>   /1/metadata/sandbox - Token is invalid. 2012-08-23 03:10:12.920
>   PageFlipper[66893:c07] Error loading metadata: Error
>   Domain=dropbox.com Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (dropbox.com error 401.)" UserInfo=0x23263fe0 {path=/, error=Token is
>   invalid.}

```
-(IBAction)addDropBox:(id)sender{
    if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:[self parentViewController]];
    }
    [[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/"];
    restClient = nil;
};
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. In my case the problem was that I did set the restClient **before** the user was connected. In this case the userId is not set and the token is invalid.

My getter for restClient now looks like this:

```
- (DBRestClient *)restClient
{
    if (_restClient == nil) {
        if ( [[DBSession sharedSession].userIds count] ) {
            _restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
            _restClient.delegate = self;
        }
    }

    return _restClient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the code to the following.

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:(UINavigationController *)[[appDelegate window] rootViewController]];
```