# Dropbox sdk 401 Error getting for iPhone 5 but not in iPhone 6 for the same app in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I referred below url and try to solve the issue but still not able to fix the issue.
Please help me out.

[Dropbox SDK 401 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086603/dropbox-sdk-401-error)

My app is working in iPhone 6 but while running the same app in iPhone 5 or 5s its showing the error:

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/metadata/dropbox/ALLCREW.TXT - (401)           No auth method found.
2014-12-11 16:58:14.628 user_schedule_3[2331:112832] Error loading metadata: Error   Domain=dropbox.com Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error   401.)" UserInfo=0x7fbb50d851c0 {path=/ALLCREW.TXT, error=No auth method found.}.
```

the code is given below: 
AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
DBSession *dbSession = [[DBSession alloc]
                        initWithAppKey:@"******h4xl9l4o"
                        appSecret:@"*******1ujh8"
                        root:kDBRootDropbox]; // either kDBRootAppFolder or   kDBRootDropbox
[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
 // NSString *listValue = @"NAME";
 return YES;
}


  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation {
   if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        NSLog(@"dropbox linked successfully!");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateRoot"    object:nil];
        NSLog(@"came out");
        // At this point you can start making API calls
    } 
    return YES;
} 
// Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
return NO;
 }
```

View controller:

```
   - (IBAction)didPressLink {
   if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
    [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
    NSLog(@"did press link is linked");
 } else {
    NSLog(@"did press link is reached");
 }
 }



  NSString *filename = @"ALLCREW.TXT";
 NSString *localDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *localPath = [localDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
[self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/ALLCREW.TXT"];
//[self.restClient loadFile:@"/ALLCREW.TXT" intoPath:localPath];
NSString *contentOfFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:localPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *stringWithEnter = [contentOfFile componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];



- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client
loadMetadataFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Error loading metadata: %@", error);
}



- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedFile:(NSString *)localPath
   contentType:(NSString *)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
NSLog(@"File loaded into path: %@", localPath);
[self getEntry ];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[spinner stopAnimating];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = true;
}



- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadFileFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"There was an error loading the file: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing "dropbox linked successfully" after authorizing? I don't see where in your code you actually make the metadata call, but are you sure auth is complete before you do that?

Comment: @Iftikhar, be sure to take the time to format/indent your code after pasting it into your question. It's pretty hard to read right now. :) Adding comments to separate chunks of code also helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The solution ended up being that you had to add:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");
            // At this point you can start making API calls
        }
        return YES;
    }
    // Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
    return NO;
}
```

You seem to have this code in:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation;
```

Moving the code to `handleOpenURL:` should fix the issue.

Also make sure to link Security.framework!

Source: http://innofied.com/integration-of-dropbox-in-ios-applications/

Comment: You may also need to remove openURL: from your code.